# find and everything including other tags with regex

Tags: regex, replace, find, wildcard, dreamweaver

I am trying to find everything from one div to the start of another and include everything in between, even if there is a line break and even if there is other tags and php functions in between.

I want it to start the search at `<div="constant-strip">` and end on  `<?php` include....

and i want it to delete everything inside the and everything that comes after `<div="constant-strip">` until it reaches the `<?php` include

even though there are other `<?php` and `<div>` tags between those.

I have searched everywhere, but all the regex and wildcard etc. searches i can find, people want to stop at the end of the div and don't include divs that are inside it or only apply to text etc...

all the `([^<])` and i've tried `([\s\S])+` and all those, but none of them work
basically i want to change this:

```
<div id="constant_strip" class="clearfix">
<div class="clearfix"><a href="<?php echo $division ?>_brands.php">
<img src="images/people.png" width="22" height="21" style="<?php echo $stripColour ?>" />View our suppliers</a></div>

<div id="call">Call us: 021 323 4088</div>

</div>
</div>

<?php include('/footer.php'); ?>
```

and turn it into just this: `<?php include('/footer.php'); ?>`
the problem is that it doesn't have exactly the same information on every page

Comment: Please recheck formatting, I might have missed something.

Comment: basically i want to change this:

Comment: Give an example of the text and what you want to match.

Comment: *it doesn't have exactly the same information on every page* => how does it differ? [edit] your question if you add information

Comment: i have edited the post, it was too large to reply here with for some reason

Comment: some pages have different classes on the id="constant_strip" some have different phone numbers depending on the division - the reason why i want to delete this is so that i can move the info into the footer.php file, and change the number to be dynamic based on what the $division is which i have sitting waiting on the new footer.php file, i just need to remove it from every other page and i don't want to go through over 1000 files removing it manually

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will match the middle part, you want to replace:

```
(?<=<div id="constant_strip" class="clearfix">)[\s\S]*?(?=<\?php include)
```